# SQL Query to SUM values from column using the same ID from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables like below;

```
table1
===========================
| table1_ID | table1_name |
===========================
|     1     |      A      |
|     2     |      B      |
===========================

table2
======================================
| table2_ID | table2_qty | table2_ID |
======================================
|     22    |      4     |     A     |
|     23    |      9     |     A     |
|     24    |     12     |     B     |
|     25    |     23     |     B     |
======================================
```

and the ouput should look like this:

```
================================
| table1_ID | name | total_qty |
================================
|     1     |   A  |     13    |
|     2     |   B  |     35    |
================================
```

"table2 ID , name & the total sum value of 'table2_qty' with the same ID from 'table1_ID'"

I tried this , but the results isn't like what I want.

```
SELECT table1.table1_ID, table1.table1_name,            
SUM(table2.table2_qty) As total_qty 
FROM table1, table2 
GROUP BY table1.table1_ID, table1.table1_name;
```

How to get that results in SQL? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using a correleated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
    (
        select sum(t2.table2_qty)
        from table2 as t2
        where t2.table2_id = t1.table1_name
    ) as total_qty
from table1 as t1
```

You can also `join` and aggregate:

```
select t1.table1_id, t1.table1_name, sum(t2.table2_qty) as total_qty
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.table2_id = t1.table1_name
group by t1.table1_id, t1.table1_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested query:

```
select t1.table1_id, t2.name, t2.total_qty
from table1 t1
join (
    select table2_id name, sum(table2_qty) total_qty
    from table2
    group by table2_id
) t2 on t2.name = t1.table1_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your attempt is aggregating on a cross join query since you use comma separated tables in `FROM` clause.

```sql
FROM table1, table2
```

MS Access uses this older SQL syntax since its dialect does not yet support explicit `CROSS JOIN` to clearly show what you are attempting. I have [suggested](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) such support among other features.

Consequently, your aggregation runs on the [cartesian product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of both tables which pairwise matches *every* combination of rows in both tables. So likely your groupings and totals are much larger than expected.

To fix, simply turn `CROSS JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t1.table1_ID
     , t1.table1_name
     , SUM(t2.table2_qty) AS total_qty 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.table1_ID = t2.table1_ID
GROUP BY t1.table1_ID
       , t1.table1_name;
```